# Window.postMessage doesn't work if fired immediately after window.open

Tags: javascript, postmessage

I've this simple script that opens a window using `window.open` and then sends a messages to it using the `postMessage` API. But using this script I'm not able to receive the message on the newly opened window.

```
const popup = window.open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/random.html");
popup.postMessage("", window.location.href);
```

But, if I put the `postMessage` call inside a timeout, then everything works as expected.

```
const popup = window.open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/random.html");
setTimeout(() => {
  popup.postMessage("", window.location.href);
}, 2000);
```

And the script that I'm using to listen to the message being sent is as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  alert("Message received");
});
```

What is the issue here? I was expecting this to work without the timeout. I want to send a message right when I'm opening the new window.

Comment: Until the resource is fetched you window points to an `about:blank` document, which doesn't care the slighests about your message. You want to wait for your own doc has loaded before trying to talk to it.

Comment: @Kaiido And how can I wait for doc to be loaded, I can't do `window.addEventListerner("DOMContentLoaded", ...)` because the window I'm trying to open is in a different origin.

Comment: You can still do window.onload.

Comment: @Kaiido No, you cannot do window.onload on a cross origin window object. I just tried and it's not working.

Comment: Hmm right.. sorry I got confused. Do you manage both pages? You could send a message to your main window from the popup using `opener.postMessage()`.

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah right! That works thanks! If you want you can post an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you have a reference to the new window open, you can add an event listener and wait for load:

```
const popup = window.open("http://127.0.0.1:3000/random.html");
popup.addEventListener('load', () => {
    executeMethod();
});
```

However, if you are opening a site on another origin you will be blocked by Browser same-origin policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

But if you manage both apps as @Kaiido suggested, you can post a message back to app1 using `window.opener.postMessage()` once the app finishes loading.

I hope this helps someone!